# TailwindCSS grid and grid-cols not working properly

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I've been using TailwindCSS throughout a NextJS project without any issues at all until I decided to implement a table component. In this table component I was planning on using the `divide-y` class from tailwind, however, given that for the class to work, the component has to also have the `grid` and `grid-col-n` class. Now I've done that, created a div with both the `grid` `grid-cols-1`.

The problem is the following: `grid` seems to work fine, when I inspect using the web inspector I can see the div having a `display: grid` but the fractions are now working properly as the `grid-cols-1` should translate to a `grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr))`, but the inspector shows `grid-template-colums:1fr 2fr`

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TY0W.png)
[web inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEMNU.jpg)

Comment: Upon further reading I found out that there's a table class in Tailwind, however the problem will show up later if I do try to use a grid

Comment: I'm not sure why the value for `grid-cols-1` is being overridden, but in this case you could make it important with `!grid-cols-1` to ensure that it's applied.

Comment: Thanks, that actually solves it. I'd still would like to know the reason why it get overrided. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post images of code, anything text-based should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).